# Rails generate scaffold_controller of a Join Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Is there a way to `rails g scaffold_controller Model [attributes]` for a join model? In particular I wonder whether the command (if exists) creates appropriate forms with fields for foreign keys.

I found no references on the official Rails' documentation.

### edit:

I have the following Models:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Note that `Appointment` contains several other attributes, and I can't use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

I would like to `rails g scaffold_controller Appointment` (or a similar command) in order to automatically get the `appointments_controller` with all the actions, and all the views (and form) to create a new Appointment and set the appropriate foreign keys.

Comment: If you try this `rails g scaffold_controller YourModel props:has_many`  you're going to get `_form.html.erb` generated and inside you're gonna get `<%= f.input :props %>` . Was that what you're looking for? How did you come up to this question? I mean how difficult is to write this in a view. Maybe I don't have enough context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Being the Model a Join Model between 2 other Models, it contains the 2 other Models' foreign keys.

I'd like to generate the controller, with the relative actions and views, set to handle the creation of a new Join Model. I added some context to my question in order to make it clearer.

Comment: Do you have other attributes in the join model besides the foreign keys? If all you have in the join model are references, you can use has_and_belongs_to_many declaration in both Patient and Physician. Then  add a references input inside one of the Patient or Physician form.

Comment: Yes, I have other attributes in it, and I'd like to have a "stand alone" form. By this I mean I'd like to render the form in the `appointments/new.html.erb` view.